# handling images, videos, docs for custom cms

Tags: php, image, content-management-system, assets, concept

I am in the process of building a CMS using php, however I am struggling on how to handle the various different assets that a dynamic page could serve, typically an average page will contain pictures of various sizes(thumb, body, main, etc), inline images and various different assets(pdf, flv, mp4, doc, etc).

At the moment a user can upload assets and create a folder on the server, I just wanted some techniques and concepts on how to manage this in terms of deleting, editing and linking to my dynamic pages within the cms? I already have a content table which contains all the content(meta_stuff, title, friendly_url, content_text, etc).

On upload should a reference be stored somewhere in say a asset table? 
Should all paths to assets(images, docs, videos,etc) be stored in one table? or separate for each asset?
Should multiple image sizes(small, medium, large, etc) be stored in different fields e.g(assetid, smallpath, mediumpath, largepath?
What technique to use to link assets to the dynamic page? should this be a joined table or single? how do I go about retrieving the different assets for a page several pdfs and several images?
How to handle deleting of assets as this could be referenced to another dynamic page?
and anything else you think would be beneficial?

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic things to keep in mind when dealing with resources (videos, images, documents..) in a scenario similar to what you're describing.

You'd want is to know **what**'s being uploaded, **what kind** of stuff are being uploaded and **who**'s uploading. To do that, it's good to have the following tables:

**Edit:** Sorry about the mistake, `asset_types.asset_type_id` should be linked to `assets.asset_type_id` and NOT `assesst.asset_id`

[image]

(Note: This is just an outline, of course you'll have more fields)

This model makes it easy to do the following tasks

- Upload: When something is uploaded, you store it somewhere (with the correct
  `.htaccess` configurations) then store that path in the table.
- Delete: When the user is trying to delete something, you check if he's the owner.
- When you want to add a new type, you don't need to create a new table.

Hopefully this will put you in the right direction.

**Update**: Answering your comment, when a user wants to add an image to an article for example, you have two options here:

1. The user is presented with a button/select menu/whatever to choose the desired image, once clicked it will add `<img src=LINK_TO_RESOURCE" />` to the body of the content (Make sure you protect yourself from XSS).

   OR
2. You use your own simple markup, when the user clicks on an image this `[[PREFIX_IMG:IMG_ID]]` will be added to the body of the content, when the content is viewed you'll replace that "tag" with `<img src="LINK_TO_RESOURCE" />` which you've acquired using `IMG_ID`.

**2nd Update**: Well you have a couple of options to handle resources that aren't directly embedded in the "articles" themselves.

1. You can have a field in the "articles" table you can call `summary` for example, and one more column to the `assets` table which you can call `asset_sub_type` and have different types like `summary`. Then when you want to view the summary you fetch the summary text/title from database and you add the resource to it.
2. (This is the technique I use) When fetching the summary from the database I see which image is the database that is related to that article and the resize it on the fly with PHP and append it to the summary.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I never thought about using owners good idea. 

What happens when a user uploads a thumbnail image, main image and now wants to add this to several content pages, should these paths now be added to the actual content table themselfs or should there be another table that contains both content table id and asset id? or some other method?

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer, sorry I wasn't so clear with my question, I understand this concept in regards to inline images within the actual content, however I am talking in regards to the images that are not in the article content, the images that can be used to list articles, list video thumbnails or features like if you take a look at http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/

Comment: For instance a single content page could have several associated images, large image for the content, medium image to be shown in features, thumbnail image to be shown in lists of all contents etc. I was wondering how the system should handle that? Thanks for all your help

Comment: @user1511907, Updated. Note:this is as far as I can help you. If you need anything else, hire someone to either do it for you or teach you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Adnan, your techniques have helped me a lot. the main issue I was struggling with was images not in the article themselves and your summary method is what I implement or something similar. Cheers :)